# ASP MVC 4: How to generate outgoing URL with same numbers of segment passed in the incoming URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with a 5 numbers of segment and they are all optional.

**ex:**

```
public ActionResult View(string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4, string p5)
{ 

}
```

so if i type in the URL like this: `domain.com/View/p1/p2/p3/p4/`

how to generate an outgoing URL with the same numbers and value of the incoming URL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "*outgoing URL*"? If that's the URL your action handles then the URL shouldn't change once the view is served.

Comment: @James - Outgoing URL is the link generated by the asp mvc application (generated by your code)

Comment: "*Outgoing URL*" isn't really the correct terminology... So you effectively want to re-use the same URL in your view?

Comment: yes i want to re-use the same URL, but i want to change the last segment of the URL. i think the terminology i used is correct. @James - you may visit this site http://mattrandle.me/mvc-outgoing-urls/ it also used the same terminology. thanks.

Comment: just because someone else used that terminology doesn't mean it's correct. Let me re-phrase...in my opinion, "*outgoing URL*" doesn't make sense. URLs have no notion of outgoing/incoming - they are simply an address. In your example, you want to *generate* a URL server-side to display it in your view.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry i found the code, after all playing with the URL helper, i found it.

for those of you have the same problem, you can use `Url.Action("actionName");`

to maintain the values of the incoming parameters.

and in case you want to change the last portion of the URL

you can use `Url.Action("actionName", new { p4 = newValue });`

Comment: you didn't really describe a very clear problem for which to answer yourself.

Comment: God knows that is not true. i have been working this for days now. i just trying to solve it on my own before posting a question, after i posted that question, then i discovered the code. but if that is your opinion i will respect it. thanks for the comment